# How to format the validation summary Key value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I've created a little helper that I can use like this:

```
= render 'shared/form_errors', resource: @user

---

- if resource.errors.any?
  #popupErrors
    %ul
      - resource.errors.each do |field, error|
        %li
          %strong= field
          = error
```

---

Here's what I'm getting:

[image]

How can I display `Password Confirmation` instead of `password_confirmation` in the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.humanize.titleize` this will remove the underscores and capitalize each word.

```
2.0.0-p451 :003 > "password_confirmation".humanize.titleize
 => "Password Confirmation"
```

Here is what the helper would look like.

```
- if resource.errors.any?
  #popupErrors
    %ul
      - resource.errors.each do |field, error|
        %li
          %strong= field.to_s.humanize.titleize
          = error
```

Comment: Since `field` is a Symbol, I had to convert to string first. `field.to_s.humanize.titleize`.